# JIRA - SharePoint 2013 On-Premise Integration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there a way to connect JIRA with SharePoint 2013 On-premise?
I have a SharePoint 2013 On-primes Project Site. I want to get the JIRA tickets into this SharePoint Site.

**Client Side & Cost-free Integration would be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

[Jira Cloud REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/) is the primary way to interact with Jira remotely, whether you are building an app, scripting interactions with Jira or developing any other integration.

Now since you have support of JIRA REST Apis, you can have following options

1. A JS REST code to get the details from JIRA platform and convert it into fine HTML. This JS file can be added to content editor web part. (*I have done this kind of to get news from 3rd party platform, just usual REST calls are required.*)
2. CSOM is also an option if you want to use managed coding practice.

Comment: I guess we have JIRA on-premise and SharePoint is on a different domain than JIRA.

Comment: @harshalgite if they are in same network then nothing to worry. Only thing you need to find out is how to make REST calls on JIRA on-prem server. I believe you can get these details from JIRA site and support. Also try those REST APIs which are used for cloud version just as a try and error method, (Of course change the URL)

Answer (score 0):

OOTB it is not possible to integate JIRA with SharePoint.

But, you can always use the connectors available for integration of JIRA with SharePoint.

I found [this](https://docs-staging.servicerocket.com/display/CFSPJ/Installation+Guide+for+SharePoint+2013) connector more useful.

Also, I Found similar [question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f89c7821-e4c7-4405-ac64-9d525e9683d4/sharepoint-integration-with-jira-bug-tracking-tool) on social technet.